# how to add data-attributes to snapengage button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was wondering if there was anyway to add data attributes to the SnapEngage button.

http://snapengage.com/

I tried to do this through jquery but it did not work.

```
 $("#SnapABug_Button").data("data-step", '8');
 $("#SnapABug_Button").data("data-intro", "click on this");
```

any suggesstions.  I want to add the data attributes "data-intro" and "data-step" so that this button may work with intro.js
http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

Thank you

Comment: why do you know it didn't work

Comment: when i inspected the element the data attributes were not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like you want:

```
$("#SnapABug_Button").data("step", '8');
$("#SnapABug_Button").data("intro", "click on this");
```

Currently, your selector will change data value of element with attribute `data-data-step` not `data-step`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method to add an attribute

```
 $("#SnapABug_Button").attr("data-step", '8');
 $("#SnapABug_Button").attr("data-intro", "click on this");
```